# Cluster Performance Tuning for Concurrent Requests

Tags: azure-data-explorer, adx

I'm trying to optimize my cluster based on the usage profile. In my scenario, I want to ingest historical data only once, then use the cluster only for running queries. On the documentation, it says the default limit for request concurrency is calculated as `Cores-Per-Node x 10`. Since I want to use the cluster only for querying data, can I increase the limit? Is there a best practice about this?

Answer (score 0):

to my understanding, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-on-request-concurrency) answers your questions. specifically - see parts in italic:

> **Limit on request concurrency**
>
> Request concurrency is a limit that a cluster imposes on several
> requests running at the same time.
>
> - The default value of the limit depends on the SKU the cluster is running on, and is calculated as: `Cores-Per-Node x 10`.
>
>   - For example, for a cluster that's set up on D14v2 SKU, where each machine has 16 vCores, the default limit is 16 cores x10 = 160.
> - *The default value can be changed by configuring the request rate limit policy of the default workload group.*
>
>   - *The actual number of requests that can run concurrently on a cluster depends on various factors. The most dominant factors are
>     cluster SKU, cluster's available resources, and usage patterns. The
>     policy can be configured based on load tests performed on
>     production-like usage patterns.*
>
> *For more information, see [Optimize for high concurrency with Azure Data
> Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/high-concurrency).*

Comment: Yes, but the documentation doesn't give any clue about my use case scenario. I can monitor the resource utilization and make changes, but I was wondering if anyone had a similar scenario and tuned the cluster.